# How do I open a JInternalFrame centered in a JDesktopPane?

Tags: java, swing, center, jinternalframe, jdesktoppane

I am adding a bunch of `JInternalFrame`s into a `JDesktopPane`, as the user selects to open various features through the menus. But I would like the internal frames to open centered in the desktop pane, as opposed to the upper left, where they seem to default.

How can I specify that the JInternalFrames open centered, or move them to the center after opening?

```
jDesktopPane.add(jInternalFrame); // jInternalFrame is not centered!
```

Comment: You should get the with and height of the screen, and make some math to set the X and Y for the JInternalFrame. I've not done that in years, so i can't give you the complete methods. Sorry

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For reference, here is the solution I used, based on dogbane's advice:

```
Dimension desktopSize = desktopPane.getSize();
Dimension jInternalFrameSize = jInternalFrame.getSize();
jInternalFrame.setLocation((desktopSize.width - jInternalFrameSize.width)/2,
    (desktopSize.height- jInternalFrameSize.height)/2);
```

Answer (score 4):

Work out the top-left corner of the new location (based on the size of the `JDesktopPane` and `JInternalFrame`) and then call [`JInternalFrame.setLocation`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setLocation%28int,%20int%29).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Netbeans (which is recommended for desktop apps) you just need to:

1. Select the form, right click and then properties;
2. Go to code tab;
3. Change "Form size policy" from "Generate Pack()" to "Generate Resize
   Code";
4. Form Position (option above Form size policy) will be available.

Now you can set the for position as you wish :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the Window.setLocationRelativeTo(Component) method, which will center the window relative to a specified component. Instead of passing in a JDesktopPane, you might want to obtain the parent frame for a component, since otherwise, your JInternalFrame will be centered according to whichever component you pass in.

Here is a code sample:

```
private void showDialog(Dialog dialogToCenter, Component button) {
    Frame frame = JOptionPane.getFrameForComponent(button);
    dialogToCenter.setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
    dialogToCenter.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: I believe setLocationRelativeTo is only available for Windows, not JInternalFrames (which don't inherit from Window). Maybe I am missing something, but can you use this method with a JInternalFrame instead of a JDialog?

Comment: Sorry, you're correct, I mistakenly thought that JInternalFrame extended from Window.

Answer (score 0):

Add this void

```
public void addCentered(Component jif) {        
    desktopPane.add(jif);
    jif.setLocation((desktopPane.getWidth()-jif.getWidth())/2, (desktopPane.getHeight()-jif.getHeight())/2);
    jif.setVisible(true);
}
```

and when adding the jInternalFrame call:

```
addCentered(jifName);
```